# Invalid attempt to read when no data is present at Reader show empty

Tags: c#

system.invalid operation exception invalid attempt to read when no data is present after while loop Reader show Empty.

```
byte[] fingerprint()   
{
    OpenConnection();
    SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    SqlDataReader Reader;
    command.CommandText = "SELECT fp,name FROM fptable";
    Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    // Reader= command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    try
    {
        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            Reader.GetValue(0);
            String name = Reader.GetValue(1) as String;
            byte[] temps = Reader.GetValue(0) as byte[];
            list.Add(temps);
            names.Add(name);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    byte[] temp = Reader.GetValue(0) as byte[]; //**error at this point**
    // byte[] temp = Reader["fp"] as byte[];
    // MakeReport(list.Count+""+names.Count);
    return temp; 
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to read again from the reader at that point? At that point your code has reached the end of the data returned by the query (exit from the loop) so it is normal to have that error. No data to read....

Comment: Your reader ends on the end of the while loop you can't keep reading with it

Answer (score 1):

Your data has been already retrieved and stored in the list.
In the while loop the Reader is enumerating on the resultset and has moved to the index where no data is present.

Please use the List (list and names) to work further on that data.

On side note - The data you have retrieved is from a table and related, so you might want to use dictionary instead of the list or some other complex object.